# T-SQL, how to get IDs that visit X amount of location within X amount of time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

T-SQL question, I been trying to find the best/optimal solution for this one.

Say we have this theoritical table

```
----------------------------------- 
ID | DATETIME | Location 
11 | 1/27 3:30pm | a 
11 | 1/27 3:31pm | b 
11 | 1/27 3:32pm | c 
22 | 2/14 1:10pm | g 
22 | 2/14 1:12pm | i 
22 | 2/15 5:48pm | w 
55 | 3/18 8:48pm | d 
55 | 3/18 9:48pm | e 
---------------------------
```

I want to create a query that return IDs that have been in 2 or more different locations within 5 minutes. In this case if you look at the table, ID: 11 and 22 visits 2 or more different location within 5 minutes, thus it should return ID 11 and 22. How do I develop a query that returns the IDs that been to X amount of location within X amount of time in minutes?

Comment: Does "best/optimal" mean laziest on your part, smallest memory footprint, minimal I/O in some specific configuration, ... ? Without specific metrics we cannot provide a Free & Optimal solution. (Unless "... return ... within 5 minutes" is the performance goal.)

Comment: hint : use `CROSS APPLY`

Comment: next time you present a datetime column as sample data please use as more complete format *yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss* is suggested & by the way id 22 does not have 2 or more visits within 5 minutes

Comment: @HABO best/optimal - speed. thanks

Comment: @ Used_By_Already I apologize for the format, I was doing a pseudocode of the table and looking for a general approach on finding this solution. Thanks for the answer, I'm taking a look at your cross apply. Id 22 does have 2 or more visits within 5 minutes at 1:10pm and 1:12pm. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using cross apply

```
select t.*, ca.num_visit
from table1 as t
cross apply (
  select count(*) num_visit
  from table1 as c
  where c.id = t.id
  and c.DATETIME > t.DATETIME
  and c.DATETIME <= dateadd(minute,5,t.DATETIME)
  ) ca
where num_visit >= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that the locations are different on each row for a given id, you can use `lead()`/`lag()`:

```
select id, datetime
from (select t.*,
             lead(datetime) over (partition by id order by datetime) as next_datetime
      from t
     ) t
where next_datetime < dateadd(minute, 5, datetime);
```

This is not a general solution to the problem.  But it does solve the particular example you have in your question.